# Why am I getting three errors when trying to use a returned value to create a chart?

Tags: reactjs

```js
        {this.state.selectedChart.map(item => {
          console.log(item.name)
          return  <div className="chartDisplayItem">
            <item.name data={data} options={options} />
            </div>
        })}
```

`item.name` returns `Bar`. I'm trying to get this working as a chart but get the errors of.

1. Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
2. Warning:  is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
3. Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

Comment: can you please try to patiently read these 3 warning messages one by one and try to understand them first by yourself? they are pretty self-descriptive

Answer (score 0):

- `<div className="chartDisplayItem">` you should pass unique key to the div, have a look at doc here https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
- `<item.name` is not an HTML element, better to wrap it as a functional component and then render it, e.g., `<Item values={item.attributes} />` but here `Item` will be a different component, which will render the items on the basis of its attributes for example `name`
- `<item.name` is not an HTML element, it's your custom name, DOM will not recognize a node named `bar`.

Comment: The perfect solution will be to read the @flainsky comment and read the react docs to figure out the warning and errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Warrning 1:
> Use key attribute for html elements or React Components and initialize with index like below codes

> Warning 2: Change item.name to Item.Name

> Warning 3: when you dont use PascalCase for React Component browser known your Component as html element and warn unknown html emelent

```
        {this.state.selectedChart.map((Item, index) => {
      console.log(Item.name)
      return  <div key={index} className="chartDisplayItem">
        <Item.name data={data} options={options} />
        </div>
    })}
```

Comment: `Item` is not defined.

Comment: you must change item component difination first

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: pleas share item.name body

Comment: item returns `{name: "Bar", id: 1}` and so on for every other value. `item.name` would return `Bar` only.

Comment: item.name is not a component so you can not use that like components. edit you question and share your component completely